# 1С 8.3 (обычное). Как получить новое значение строки табличного поля без переоткрывания документа?

Tags: 1с

Вид табличного поля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значение меняется с помощью сканера штрихкодов.

Для имитации сканера с помощью кнопки изменяю значение табличного поля:

```
ДокКоличество = Документы.ЗаказНаряд.НайтиПоНомеру("КТ3405").Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
ДокКоличество.Товары.Количество = ДокКоличество.Товары.Количество+1;
```

Но запись нужно произвести не в обработчике кнопки, а в обработчике документа, сканер же не нажмет на кнопку, а сразу изменяет значение количества (нас интересует, чтобы если количество товара изменится, то он его покажет).

По логике нужно сделать так:

1. Изменять значение количества товара в табличном поле;
2. Записать значение `ДокКоличество.Записать();`. Значение не хочет в форме документа записаться (а в обработчике кнопки записывается).
3. Обновить значение с помощью: `ЭтотОбъект.Прочитать()`, либо `ЭтаФорма.Прочитать()` и т.п.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: "нас интересует, чтобы если количество товара изменится, то он его покажет" - покажет как, что?
"Значение не хочет в форме документа записаться (а в обработчике кнопки записывается)." - почему не хочет? Код есть? Или текст ошибки?
Старайтесь формулировать вопросы более корректно. Каким образом количество меняется сканером? Каждый раз просто плюсует единичку, при сканировании товара, если находит его в таблице?

Answer (score 0):

Новое (оно же текущее) значение хранится в Табличной части документа;

```
// Объект.Товары - табличная часть документа

// Получим строку тч на которой стоит курсор
_Стр = Элементы.ЭлТчТовары.ТекущиеДанные;  // не помню точно, но вроде
// это можно сделать только &НаКлиенте

// Далее можно Прочитать значения 
_Номенклатура = _Стр.Номенклатура;
_Количество = _Стр.Количество;
_НомерСтроки = _Стр.НомерСтроки;  // НомерСтроки
// Исходные значения доступны при обращении через Ссылка
_Товары = Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект().Товары;
_Стр0 = _Товары[_НомерСтроки - 1]  // Индекс начинается с 0
// Обращаю внимание, что если порядок строк в тч будет изменен, по _НомерСтроки обратимся не туда куда нужно ! Лучше искать старое значение по Номенклатуре + ?!

// Старые значения: Ссылка.* ; Новые значения Объект.* ;
```